# Proper way to convert PDF to word from bash command-line

Tags: text-processing, pdf, libreoffice, pdftk

I need to convert 1K pdf files to doc on a debian server. I can convert a PDF to word using libreoffice commandline:

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to doc Sample-doc-file-100kb.pdf
```

Or using soffice:

```
soffice --nocrashreport --nologo --nolockcheck --nofirststartwizard --invisible --headless --convert-to doc Sample-doc-file-100kb.pdf
```

The main problem with the above two commands, is that the doc file doesn't include images in the pages, it only contains the formatted text. Is there a better way to convert pdf to doc, including also the images present in the pdf? I am not interested in web services like zamzam, I need to do that from command-line on the server. Thank you.

Comment: an idea maybe dose it work to convert it to html and then to doc?

Answer (score 3):

You could try abiword software.
e.g:

```
abiword --to=doc example.pdf
```

Comment: Already tried, it only converts the text without the images

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it by using this:

```
libreoffice --infilter=="writer_pdf_import" --headless \
--convert-to doc:"writer_pdf_Export" Brief.pdf
```

It gives me the same output as @igiannak's answer.

Comment: After doing this `file` detects the resultant `Brief.doc` as a pdf, and libreoffice opens it in Draw. So I don't think this really works.

Answer (score 0):

any direct command line interface command is available with pdf to docx conversion including images present in the pdf and I tried libreoofice and soffice commands it was giving only simple formatted text like any other pywin32 com clinet library is available on linux/ubuntu during pdf to word conversion

import os
import sys

import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

def covx_to_pdf(infile, outfile):
"""Convert a Word .docx to PDF"""

```
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(infile)
doc.SaveAs(outfile, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

this code is working on windows machine for pdf to word conversion
but this package can not support to linux/debian platforms.can we have any suggestion for this same implementation on Linux/debian for pdf to word conversion

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/447651)

Comment: @chakka krishnamurty Would you provide a piece of code then to share with us?